# Separating out user management and Stripe payments into a second app and linking via API. My Neo4j knowledgebase

Tags: ruby-on-rails, neo4j, stripe-payments

I've built a database in Neo4j and use Rails with [Neo4jrb](https://github.com/neo4jrb/neo4j) as an easy way to manipulate the database.  For reasons I explain below, below I call this a knowledgebase (kb) instead of database.

I starting working with a friend who wants to provide access to the kb for users of his app.  So I built an API in rails so he can access it.

Now my friend and I are talking about building a membership site with subscription payments.  So I figured I needed to figure out how to build Stripe subscription payments into my app.  I found this [great tutorial by RailsApps](https://github.com/RailsApps) which in terms of functionality does exactly what I need, it relies on a gem called [Payola](https://github.com/peterkeen/payola) which makes Stripe integration easy.  Payola is great but it works with ActiveRecord, not Neo4j.  I was thinking I'd have to figure out how to do what Payola does with Neo4j.

But now I have the idea of just building a separate app using the RailsApp+Payola approach, and then just hooking that app up to my kb's API.

The reason I say knowledgebase is because its purpose is to structure knowledge within a particular domain.  I use the graph database Neo4j because the graph-based data model suits this goal, for example (object of type A) -[has a certain influence on]-> (object of type B).

So I like my idea of using a separate app for managing users and subscriptions because then I avoid mixing app specific data with domain knowledge in the database.

So I guess my concern is, what might I be missing?  Will speed be a concern if this membership site has to access an API every time a page loads?  Would there be unusual security concerns?

Answer (score 0):

It's perfectly fine to use another database next to neo4j. You should always use the database that fits your needs I think :)